# Bootstrap datepicker shows incorrect date format

Tags: jquery, html, laravel

I use bootstrap datepicker to get a date input to my HTML page. I get the current date from the back end by Laravel code as $currentDate.

HTML:

```
<input type="text" name="manifest-date" class="datepicker calender form-control" placeholder="mm/dd/yyyy" id="manifest-date" value="{{$currentDate}}" />
```

jQuery:

```
$.fn.datepicker.defaults.format = "M-dd-yy";
$('.datepicker').datepicker({'setDate':new Date(), autoclose: true});
```

Laravel:

```
->with('currentDate', date('M-j-y'))
```

As the date format and the value of $currentDate, I get Oct-22-18 in console but input field shows it as 2018-10-22. What is wrong here?

Comment: this is because you are setting the datepicker date as new Date(), remove the `setDate`

Comment: Removed but the issue is still there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to provide new date. Use the jQuery code with format and autoclose.

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker({format : 'M-dd-yy', autoclose: true});
```